# Why is my LINQ statement throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm using the HTML agility pack to scrape a website.  I'm looking though all the div tags that contain "a" elements for certain text.  Here is the sample code:

```
 var showLocations = (from div in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                                 from a in div.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.Name == "a")
                                 where a.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("show_locs=Y")
                                 select a).SingleOrDefault();
```

However, instead of returning null if the element cannot be found, it throws a "Null Reference Exception".  Why is that?

Comment: As a test, run these queries separately and make sure `div.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.Name == "a")` is actually returning something. It seems to me that `a` is `null`, and it might be failing when it tries to evaluate `a.Attributes["href"].Value`

Comment: It can be many things. I think that 'a' variable is null in your case. Seems as best candidate. Try to split this query into two queries.

Comment: The simplest approach would be to break the statement down into its component parts, and iterate each one manually.

Comment: Or it could be that a.Attributes["href"] is null. This would through when you call .Value. Do all your div's have "href" attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that there are `<a>` tags without `href` attributes (i.e anchors instead of links). try `a.GetAttributeValue("href", "").Contains...` instead.

Comment: Was thinking the same thing. +8

Comment: Yup, that's exactly why it was breaking.  I for some reason just assumed that anytime the linq statement wasn't successful, it would just return null.  Learn something new everyday.

Comment: LINQ isn't magic. all the expressions are C#, and follows the same rules any other C# follows.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of objects that you're dealing with that have the potential to evaluate to null, and since you're not doing null checks, some may throw a **NullReferenceException**. Possible culprits:

1. document.DocumentNode
2. a.Attributes["href"]
3. a.Attributes["href"].Value

A safe practice is to have null guards if you're unsure about the objects you're dealing with, unless you can guarantee within your encapsulated class that the objects in question won't be null.

As Jimmy pointed out in his answer, the markup you're dealing with is probably not guaranteed to have the elements or attributes you're after, and unless you can guarantee that, you need to do some defensive programming.